# How to get all links (URL) in text?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Here is a situation where I can't find a solution. I use this:

```
// creating ajax object
// ====================

function createRequestObject(){
try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
catch(e)
{
try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
catch(e)
{
try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
catch(e) { return null; }
}
}
}
```

This is for using Ajax. So I get a text from the PHP file with Ajax (http.responseText). Now I need to find all URL links in text and send another Ajax request to another PHP file that checks a link for availability with cURL reading headers. If server response is 200, then return the HTML link, if other server response or error, then return simple text link.

Can anyone help how to solve this question?

I suppose a JavaScript to work like this:

1. var PHPreturn = http.responseText.
2. turn on for() cycle to check for all words divided with backspaces and check all words for a link. if a link suites for the URL regular express, put a new function that will send new Ajax query to another PHP file for checking a link, like:

//turn on cycle that will get all words separated with backspace

```
for(...){
```

// if a word is a link with http://

```
if(regular_express == http://){
```

// replace a word[i] with loading bar, while ajax returns a response from PHP file

```
word[i].replace(word[i],'<span id="url_id"><img src="loading.gif"></span>');
```

// sending Ajax query and waiting for PHP file return

// checkURL("PHP file with GET url variable","SPAN ID");

```
checkURL("http_response.php?url="+url,"span_id");


function checkURL(url,place){
var http = createRequestObject();
if(http){
http.open("GET", url);
http.onreadystatechange = function (){
if(http.readyState == 4){
document.getElementById(place).innerHTML = http.responseText;
}
}
http.send(null);
} else {
document.location = url;
}
}
```

I don't know how all this JavaScript should be. Will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using responseXML;

```
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
txt="";
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  // your code here.
}
```